# How to see code of Monad Reader?

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

I am a beginner in Haskell, and I want to understand Reader Monad. I know how to use this monad. But I want to see the implementation of monad (particularly code of function "return"). How can I see this code?

Comment: The definition is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.html) but I would recommend reading the simplified version [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Reader_monad)

Comment: Oh, Thanks - It seems like answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have downloaded the ghc source from [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc)
It contains the definition of all the base functions
Then I open the folder in Sublime text editor which will index the source files. Then you can type `F12` on a function or `Ctrl+Shift+F` to find the implementation. You can jump back with `Alt+-`.

I actually downloaded many other Haskell libraries for easy reference.

[image: Sublime with Haskell source code folder]

Answer (score 3):

Answered [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853906/how-to-see-code-of-monad-reader#comment63166506_37853906) by [pdexter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587319/pdexter):

> The definition is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.html) but I would recommend reading the simplified version [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Reader_monad).